# How to make default application in android?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I need to add one of my app to my android such that even if it is fully formatted it remains within the android as the default installed app. Can i get help regarding it. I have my android rooted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you mentioned 'Default app' means i assume you want to make your app as 'System app'. If your phone is rooted successfully you can do this with numerous methods.

1. **File Explorer method**
   If you have a file explorer with root permission granted (ex. ES File explorer etc), it is very easy.

   - Just obtain an 'APK' file of your app.
   - Copy the APK file. Navigate to *'/system/app'*.  paste it under *'/system/app'* folder.
   - Long press 'APK' to change its properties. Under permissions property, click on change and set it to rw- r-- r--. ( Thats *user: read and write*, *group: read only* and *other: read only*. Thats it! Reboot your device.
2. **ADB method**
   Same can be done with the help of ADB. You just have to copy and paste your Apps APK file under *'/system/app'* folder.

   - To do this, connect your device to your pc and make sure you have ADB drivers are installed correctly. Also enable the usb debugging.
   - Open command prompt and type:
   - `adb shell`
   - `su`
   - `cd /data/app`
   - `mv 'your_app name' /system/app/'your_app_name'`. Replace 'your_app_name' with obviously name of your application without quotes.
   - Again exit shell and reboot.
3. **Apps method**
   This is most simple method. There are many apps available to do this task. One popular app is 'Titanium Backup'. But as per my knowledge 'convert to system app' feature is paid version only. So i prefer one of above method only.

> Tip: do the tricks only if you know what you are doing and you are familiar with android file system at your own risk.

Comment: In adb method, to get the name of your application type command 'ls' it will list all the apps installed.

Comment: Also note that there might be `/system/app-priv` which according so some sources then might be the preferred place (instead of `/system/app`) if it exists.